# How to move a vector towards an another vector in Cocos Creator?

Tags: cocoscreator

How can I move a `Vec2` instance towards an another `Vec2`. Let's say, move it half way between the two positions. I'm looking for an equivalent method (preferably a built in one) to Unity engine's `Vector2.MoveTowards` method.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what those Vectors represent.

A vector2 could represent a point in a 2 dimentional space or a line with a defined direction and magnitude.

In te first case, you can move a point (pointA) towards another (pointB) finding the vector between them and adding it to the first point.

```
Vector2 l_DiffVector = pointB - pointA;

Vector2 result = pointA + l_DiffVector/2f;
```

note that I divide the l_DiffVector by 2 so the *result* will be a point in the half way of pointA and pointB.

In the second case where a Vector2 represents a direction, it does not make sense to move one towards another because they does not represent a position in space.

I hope it is clear enough. It's difficult to tell it only with text. If you have any doubt please ask again!

Good luck!